# How do I get a linux terminal to show me the DNS domain suffix of a machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying to make a script that will ping an IP address and tell you the name of the server it is pinging.

It works....mostly

I cannot seem to figure out how to make Linux (Ubuntu more specifically) to display the dns domain suffix that is set inside of the "resolv.conf" file.

if I type "hostname" at a command prompt all I get is "ubuntu01"

I tried typing domainname and all I get is the output "(none)" which is confusing me considering I can type the hsotname of any computer on my network and it will append the DNS suffix of "solignis.local" to it just like it is supposed to.

Any ideas?

Comment: The command `hostname -f` should return the FQDN for the local host if the /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts is setup properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hostname` provides this functionality:

```
$ hostname -d
```

If you are getting `(none)` then the domain may not be set, there is also the `-y` switch for the NIS/YP domain name.

Comment: hostname -y, displays "domainname: Local domain name not set", sounds like I got some debugging to do. problem is I am pretty new to linux.

Comment: Solignis: Sounds to me like the domain is just not set on the machine, if it has one, that needs to be sorted out.

Comment: @Solignis, Look at your /etc/hosts.  There should be a entry for your system with the FQDN.

Comment: that was the problem, it works now. I looked at another server I had and I used that as an example. I had uninstalled the Ubuntu desktop network manager and there was still a commented line in there about it making the change, works now. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

The "search" and "domain" settings in resolv.conf are only for converting host names with no domain to IP addresses.

You are trying to convert a host name with no domain to a host name with a domain.

I would usually set the hostname to a host name with a domain, e.g. in /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts.

The other option would be to set up a DNS server.

Comment: I have a DNS server running its BIND9. It runs forward and reverse. You saying if I add and entry for this machine it will be good?

Comment: Yes, I think so.  Worst case, you have to run "host ubuntu01", then grab the IP address that that prints, and then run "host <IP address>".

Comment: that works...sorta. it gives me this output "21.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer ubuntu01.solignis.local." But if I run "dnsdomainname" it says dnsdomainname: Name or service not known.

Comment: What do you have in /etc/hosts?  /etc/hosts will be used in preference to DNS by default.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the computer doesn't have the domain properly configured. If there's a search domain in the resolv.conf file that you want, you can grep it out (`grep search /etc/resolv.conf`)

Comment: I just tired it and I get just the hostname, no domain suffix. I found a site that told me to try type "dnsdomainname" but it does not work for me it just makes another command prompt and moves on.

Comment: I know I set it in the resolv.conf. would "grep"ing it be the easiest I assume? I am trying do it for a perl script I starting to wonder if perl has a way to find the domain suffix, hmm well thanks for the help.